# CakePhp file not start downlaod

Tags: cakephp, download

i am newer here and with cakephp, i use MediaViews for donwloading files from server (pdf), and i am follow  media Views tutorials on cakephp.org,google, and here, but still have problem, when i click on link , i get view, but no file, nothing changes.
(book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Views.html)
my download function:

```
function download () {
$this->view = 'Media';
$params = array(
'id' => 'dino.pdf',
'name' => 'dino',
'extension' => 'pdf',
'download' => true,
'mimeType' => array('pdf' => 'application/pdf'),   
'path' => APP.'files'.DS
);
$this->set('dino',$params);
}
```

and i use var_dump for parmas, result:

```
 array(6) { ["id"]=> string(8) "dino.pdf" ["name"]=> string(4) "dino"   ["extension"]=> string(3) "pdf" ["download"]=> bool(true) ["mimeType"]=> array(1) { ["pdf"]=> string(15) "application/pdf" } ["path"]=> string(20) "D:\medium\app\files\" }
```

my file on disk:
D:\medium\app\files\dino.pdf

any one who can helps me, thank you

Comment: what cakephp version? for 2.x you should leverage the CakeResponse class instead!

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: @mark - why not still use the MediaView?  At least according to the book, it's exactly what she'd want.  (book outdated?)

Comment: MediaView is deprecated. Also CakeResponse class can do everything quite as good - and way more.

Comment: i use 2.x version cake

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333399/cakeresponse-download-file-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Please read the "correct" documentation then.
You posted a 1.3 link while working with 2.x.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakeresponse

```
$this->autoRender = false;
$this->response->type('pdf');
$this->response->file($path . $filename, array('download' => true, 'name' => $name));
```

Note that file() is >= 2.3. You might want to upgrade.

You might be able to do it this way for <= 2.2

```
$this->response->body($contentOfPdf);
$this->response->download($name);
```

Comment: thank you so much , i will try. whati is with view? i cant understand this relation, where is view ?S:

Comment: if you just serve a file (send some binary data etc), you don't need any view. makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: yea, thanks man, but only problem now is path and name of file, i get download dialog , but pdf file is 0 kb.. excuse me on fatal erros i am girl :) sorry

Comment: debug your path/filename (it should be a valid path to the existing file!). In your case probably `APP . 'files' . DS . 'dino.pdf'`

Comment: $path= APP . 'files' . DS . 'dino.pdf';
$filename='dino';
$this->response->download($path,$filename);
not working :(
i dont know how to debug vars, i user var_dump($path) but nothing changes

Comment: think. please. you cannot use a path containing already the filename and append a filename (again!) that does not contain an extension. makes no sense...

Comment: ok i modified, but no changes:
function download () {
  
  
  $this->autoRender = false;
  $this->response->type('pdf');
  $path= APP . 'files' . DS ;
  $filename='dino.pdf';
  $this->response->download($path . $filename);
}

Comment: what exactly is happening? does the file exists? `$res = file_exists($path . $file)`

Comment: doesnt look like you input anything valid into download() - even though I as well as the docs cleary point out how to.

Comment: please help me, how? i cant understand what is problem in function :(